# Find within array of objects the item having maximum value of certain property and return another property of that item

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Trying to create a function to return the Name if the price is the highest using javascript. Still learning.

```
  {
    Name: "Effective Yoga Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 10.99
  },
  {
    Name: "Yoga kit",
    type: "product",
    price: 199.99
  },
  {
    Name: "Medative surroundings",
    type: "CD",
    price: 6.00
  }
]
```

If anyone can help I would appreciate it. Thank you in advance

Comment: Please show us your attempt so that we can help with your code, not just write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to traverse your array and have *accumulator* to store the record with greatest `price` value:

```js
const src = [{Name:"Effective Yoga Habits",type:"book",price:10.99},{Name:"Yoga kit",type:"product",price:199.99},{Name:"Medative surroundings",type:"CD",price:6.00}],

    result = src
      .reduce((r, {Name,price}) => 
        price > r.price ? {Name,price} : r)
      .Name
    
console.log(result)
```